# Voracious Wurm and Trostani, Selesnya's Voice: Which trigger happens first?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Here's the situation:

[Trostani, Selesnya's Voice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrostani%2c%5d%2b%5bSelesnya%27s%5d%2b%5bVoice%5d) is in play (*Whenever another creature enters the battlefield under your control, you gain life equal to that creature's toughness*). Then, [Voracious Wurm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVoracious%20Wurm%5d) is cast (*Voracious Wurm enters the battlefield with X +1/+1 counters on it, where X is the amount of life you've gained this turn*).

Which trigger happens first?

- Gain 2 life, then the wurm enters play with 2 +1/+1 counters, or
- The wurm enters play with 0 +1/+1 counters, then gain 2 life

Comment: If they were both triggered abilities, you'd get to pick the order to put them on the stack; see for example http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/ or http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/ (it's a fairly common question).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Voracious Wurm has a replacement effect that modifies how it enters the battlefield; thus, it would come into play with 0 +1/+1 counters, and you will gain two life.

If Voracious Wurm had a triggered ability (such as "When ~ enters the battlefield, put X +1/+1 counters on it, where X is the amount of life you've gained this turn"), however, you would be able to place the triggers on the stack in whatever order you choose, meaning you could gain 2 life and put 2 counters on, or put 0 counters on and gain two life.

Relevant rules:

> 603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered
>   abilities he or she controls on the stack in any order he or she
>   chooses. (See rule 101.4.) Then the game once again checks for and
>   resolves state-based actions until none are performed, then abilities
>   that triggered during this process go on the stack. This process
>   repeats until no new state-based actions are performed and no
>   abilities trigger. Then the appropriate player gets priority.
>
> 614.1. Some continuous effects are replacement effects. Like prevention effects (see rule 615), replacement effects apply
>   continuously as events happen -- they aren't locked in ahead of time.
>   Such effects watch for a particular event that would happen and
>   completely or partially replace that event with a different event.
>   They act like "shields" around whatever they're affecting.
>   614.1d Continuous effects that read "[This permanent] enters the battlefield . . ." or "[Objects] enter the battlefield . . ." are
>   replacement effects.

Comment: So, without the word "When" it is a replacement effect, but with "When" it is triggered? Is this the only difference?

Comment: @bengoesboom CR 614.1c Effects that read "[This permanent] enters the battlefield with . . . ," "As [this permanent] enters the battlefield . . . ," or "[This permanent] enters the battlefield as . . . " are replacement effects.

Comment: @bengoesboom CR 603.1 Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as "[Trigger condition], [effect]," and begin with the word "when," "whenever," or "at." They can also be expressed as "[When/Whenever/At] [trigger event], [effect]."

Comment: replacement effects can also often be spotted by "instead"

Answer (score 6):

[Voracious Wurm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voracious%20Wurm)'s ability isn't a triggered ability. It's a *replacement effect*.

Instead of putting the Wurm on the battlefield, you put the Wurm on the battlefield and put counters on it, as one action. Only *then* do you check for triggers, like Trostani's ETB life-gain trigger.